# How to override a property setter using short form?

Tags: kotlin

I just wanna override a default setter using short form but I failed:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var progress: Int = 0
        set(value) = MathUtils.clamp(value, 0, 100)
}
```

It says `Required: Unit but found: Int`.

**What am I doing wrongly?**

Comment: Setters should not return a value.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, seems I've gotten just now, this form is used to set a lambda as setter. I thought it's an analog of `set(value) { field = value }`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property setter is the actual setter of the property and the short form is just a simplified form to have the function return the result of a single expression.

```
set(value) {
    field = MathUtils.clamp(value, 0, 100)
}
```

Now `field = value` is an assignment, not an expression, thus it can't be used here. But if you really want to implement it with the shorter form, it's still possible with a little more verbosity.

```
set(value) = run { field = MathUtils.clamp(value, 0, 100) }
```

Comment: Assigning a field value in a lambda in a short form function makes me shudder a little...

Comment: @BoristheSpider it's nothing you should do in production code, but it's possible and therefore worth noting in this context.

Comment: You can do `set(value) = run {
    field = MathUtils.clamp(value, 0, 100)
}` but like using `let` it only makes things longer.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt but it's still better that `let`. Thanks

Comment: better use `field = value.coerceIn(0, 100)`